# class from JTwitter library - Keeps giving me java.lang.NoClassDeffFoundError : winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter

Tags: java, android

I am new to java,android and stackoverflow so I hope I am giving you guys all the info you may need to resolve this.

I keep getting   **java.lang.NoClassDeffFoundError** : winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter   at run of this :

```
    package com.example.testh;



    import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class StatusActivity extends Activity {

        Twitter twitter;
        static final String TAG = "StatusActivity";
        EditText editStatus;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.status);
            editStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_input);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }



        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             final String statusText = editStatus.getText().toString();

            new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                    twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
        twitter = new Twitter("student","password");
        twitter.setStatus(statusText);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Died",e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

            Log.d("StatusActivity", "OnClicked with text : " + statusText);

        }
    }
```

I am using a third party library from jtwitter which I imported and now is in Referenced Libraries (I can not see it in the libs folther though - but as do not know what that's for, I have no idea if it should be ?)

**The LogCat:**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxhN1Muef3jYdnZBZzRyeHkxQjA/edit

PS: Line 42 in the source code is : twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");

**The Package Explorer :**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxhN1Muef3jYUDJzMlFMeThqa0U/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy jtwitter.jar to libs folder.
- Hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

u have to update build path i.e means u have to add jar, for that I did following steps

1 download yamba source code from https://github.com/twitter-university/LearningAndroidYamba

2 in that goto yamba-1 and there is a jar file jtwitter-yamba.jar update it rather than jtwitter.jar